# Removing hline when producing latex code for table in R with Hmisc package

Tags: tables, r

I have been struggling with this for some time and can't really find an answer. By default the `latex` command in `Hmisc` package cab generate code for table with `hline` on top, below header row and after the last row. Is there a way to customize this? E.g. I do not want any horizontal line in the table. Is that possible?

Comment: That seems to be a question more about R than about latex

Answer (score 1):

The Hmisc `latex` command does not appear to have an option to suppress the horizontal rules, so your options are:

1. Remove the `\hline` commands from the file produced by R using your text editor
2. Remove the `\hline` commands using a filter.  Since the `\hline`s are always written on their own lines, then if you have a sensible command shell available, you could try:

   `cat table-from-r.tex | grep -v hline >table-for-latex.tex`
3. Redefine `\hline` to do nothing: just input the table from R inside a group where you have defined `\let\hline\space`.

For example, running `latex(cars)` in R produces `cars.tex` complete with `hline` commands, but this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}    
{\let\hline\space\input{cars.tex}}
\end{document}
```

prints the table with no rules. The normal definition of `\hline` is restored at the end of the group. I suspect that option 3 is likely to be what you want to do, if you are committed to the `Hmisc` package, but you might prefer to try [`xtable`](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/xtable/index.html) which does a rather more flexible job of producing LaTeX (and HTML) versions of R data objects, and includes an option to suppress all `\hline` commands in the output.

Comment: I'd assign the definition of `\hline` to a temporary macro to not mess with `hline`s elsewhere in the document.

Comment: @1010011010 good point.  Updated.